# AWS RDS Performance Insights - view full queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm using a MySQL-Server from AWS RDS. I would like to inspect the queries made by the app to optimize them. My problem is, that almost every query is longer than 1024 chars (which is the max-size, as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.html#USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.SQLTextSize)).
So I cannot identify the query by the first 1024 chars, as thats only the SELECT-Part - the interesting parts WHERE, ORDER, and so on are truncated. Since the app uses an ORM-System, I cannot change the queries to shorten them. 
Already tried to increase the option [performance_schema_max_digest_length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-system-variables.html#sysvar_performance_schema_max_digest_length) in the parameter-group to 4096, but that has no effect (no change can be seen in the options directly on the server).
What can I do?

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean: in your first link it talks about that 1,024 limit.  It's pretty clear they are saying that's the max you can set for the performance insights dashboard.  Would the mysql log files help? (general_log, slow_query_log, etc)? If so, have a look a these settings: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQL.Generallog

Comment: Logs are activated (over 24 hours now) but nothing interesting in there :(

Comment: @cklm were you able to solve this? we're experiencing the same.

Comment: no, I was not able to solve the problem

Comment: same here! any news?

Comment: nope - didn't find a way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now, around three years later, I discovered a page in the documentation about that topic which answers my question:
[Accessing more SQL text in the Performance Insights dashboard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.UsingDashboard.SQLTextSize.html)

So for me it now works as follows:

1. parameters `max_digest_length` and `performance_schema_max_digest_length` are high enough (8192 does it in my case)
2. in performance insights, tab "Top SQL" only the first 500 chars of the general query are shown. When clicked on the plus on the left, it expands and a query with parameters is visible. Click on the dot in the first column to see the full query in the area below.

Comment: If I'm reading that page correctly, you can only change the max digest length for RDS Postgres, not RDS MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

That is a static parameter, so rebooting your instance may resolve the issue.  Please see the following explanation from the AWS docs:

> When you change a static parameter and save the DB parameter group,
>   the parameter change takes effect after you manually reboot the DB
>   instance. You can reboot a DB instance using the RDS console or by
>   explicitly calling the RebootDbInstance API action (without failover,
>   if the DB instance is in a Multi-AZ deployment). The requirement to
>   reboot the associated DB instance after a static parameter change
>   helps mitigate the risk of a parameter misconfiguration affecting an
>   API call, such as calling ModifyDBInstance to change DB instance class
>   or scale storage

[Working with Parameter groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, read that too and rebooted the instance - but no change. Maybe AWS limits that value internally to 1024 (as their performance-insights rely on that), but it would be fair to indicate that somewhere.

Comment: I just tried it on a replica and it worked without needing to restart. You may want to try to disable and re-enable performance insights.

Comment: It seems db instance rebooting and re-enabling performance insights doesn't work for MySQL 8 engine, log are is still capped by the 1024 limit.